# Worklight 6.1: how to check blackberry connectivity

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

in Worklight 6.1, as:

- WL.Client.isConnected is deprecated
- WL.Device.getNetworkInfo available on Android and iOS

How to check the connectivity for Worklight server from a Blackberry Device?

I need this to sync my data when my app is connected (which means that the worklight server is responding).

Please don't tell me to invoke a procedure and check the response status :S

Answer (score 0):

Use `WL.Client.connect(options)` For Extra Infromation check [IBM Info Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_connect.html)

Comment: thanks, i'll checked for the javascript events. (Your link is useless as i have version 6.1)